# Access data from controller in view in didInsertElement

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to access data from DashboardIndexController in DashboardIndexView

```
JP.DashboardIndexController =  Ember.Controller.extend({
  users: []
});
```

Is it possible to access users in JP.DashboardIndexView in didInsertElement?

```
didInsertElement : function(){
    console.log(this.get("controller.users").objectAt(0));
}
```

This is my DashboardIndexRoute:

```
JP.DashboardIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('users',  JP.User.find());
  }
});
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
console.log(this.get("controller.users").objectAt(0));
```

Returns data only when I go to `UsersIndex` and then back to `DashboardIndex`... I think it's something with initialization, but I don't know, how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is how to access the list of users.

This happens because the `DashboardIndexView` is inserted into the DOM before the `controller.users` is populated with data from the server.

So when the view is rendered, `controller.users` is still empty, and will asynchronously be populated after the ajax request finishes, problem is, `didInsertElement` already fired.

In order to solve this, you need to access `controller.users` from another hook.  `DidInsertElement` is the wrong place, because it will fire irrespective of whether `JP.User.find()` finished loading.

You just need to make sure that it re-fires when `JP.User.find()` is loaded even if view is already in the DOM.  Something like this:

```
JP.DashboardIndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.usersChanged();
  },
  usersChanged: function() {
    if (!this.$()) { return; } // View not in DOM
    console.log(this.get('controller.users'));
  }.observes('controller.users.@each')
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a computed property within `usersChanged`...`this.get('controller').get('model').get('length')` shows me my models are loaded, but `this.get('controller').get('total')` (a computed property) returns NaN. Any ideas?

Comment: also, this is firing each time a user is loaded. is there a trigger for when all users are loaded? thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough info to answer your first question.  For the second question, you can try to schedule the method using `Ember.run.once`; see https://gist.github.com/teddyzeenny/6029603

Comment: Thanks! I've asked another question, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726136/trouble-accessing-controllers-computed-property-from-view

Comment: This still isn't working for me. When the observer fires, the model is not yet loaded in the view. Do you know if there is a way to observe model change *after it is rendered in the view*?

Comment: Yes, you can schedule it to run in the `afterRender` queue:  `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.handleUsers);`