# Trouble accessing controller's computed property from view

Tags: ember.js

My controller has a computed property:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    grandTotal: function () {
        return this.getEach('total').reduce(function(accum, item) {
            return accum + item;
        }, 0);
    }.property('@each.total'),

});
```

but I'm having trouble accessing it with my view. Here's my view:

```
App.SummaryView = Ember.View.extend({

    templateName: 'summary',

    companiesChanged: function() {
        Ember.run.once(this, 'logCompanies');
    }.observes('controller.@each'),

    logCompanies: function() {
        console.log(this.get('controller').get('model').get('length'));
        console.log(this.get('controller').get('grandTotal'));
    }

});
```

`.get('length')` returns correctly, so I know when this is called the models are loaded. But `grandTotal` is coming back as `NaN`, even though I know it's coded correctly since it's being rendered in the template. I need to access it within my view for additional reasons.

Any ideas?

Comment: does this work: `var self = this; Ember.run.next(function() { console.log(self.get('controller.grandTotal'));  });`

Comment: it definitely has something to do with the computed property part. If I add a property to the controller: `simple: 'test'`, I can access it in the view.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with `total`? try replacing it with something simpler. `return this.getEach('total');` or `return this.get('length')` etc...

Comment: the only thing is it works if I navigate away then navigate back. doesn't that mean it has to do with the data not being loaded?

Comment: In the view, instead of observing 'controller.@each` why don't you observe `controller.grandTotal` ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the controller's computed property changes with @each.total, the view only cares about the controller's property. Thus, the view was wrongly observing @each model, when it should have just been observing `controller.grandTotal`:

```
App.SummaryView = Ember.View.extend({

    templateName: 'summary',

    companiesChanged: function() {
        Ember.run.once(this, 'logCompanies');
    }.observes('controller.grandTotal'),

    logCompanies: function() {
        console.log(this.get('controller').get('model').get('length'));
        console.log(this.get('controller').get('grandTotal'));
    }

});
```